# How to Create Facebook App Ads Using FB SDK in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I want to Create `Facebook App Ads` using `Facebook SDK` but i don't have any idea how to Create `FB App Ads`. I'm Following that Link to Create App Ads

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/creating-ads

but i don't know why use `SDK` for App Ads anyone have to Create `App Ads` using `SDK` than please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No One Answer My Question but i Find the Solution,

1.Create **Facebook App**,

2.Must Check that Your App is **Green Sign** call Not a **Red Sign**,

3.For Green Sign call You select a iOS Platform than Enter Your **XCode Project Bundle ID**,

4.Goto **App Review** and must Check **Make LoginApp public?** Click **YES**,

5.After Create Facebook App you have got `Facebook ID`

6.Implement [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) in your XCode Project.

Facebook requires you to have the **Facebook iOS SDK** to use **Facebook Mobile Apps Install Ads.**

You need to add the following code in `applicationDidBecomeActive` method of your `AppDelegate.m` file

```
(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];  
    [FBSettings publishInstall:YOUR_APP_ID];
}
```

Once you Complete with this Code than Your Work is Over here Coding Side than You Just Follow this link to Learn Create an Ads on Facebook.

Follow this [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video-api)